# Update Item in Hashset

Tags: c#, hashset

Is there a way to update an item in a hashset. I have a hashset of users and I would like to update the connectionId field.

[image: ScreenGrab of the Hashset]

Should I do the following:

1. retrieve the item, make the necessary updates
2. remove the item from hashset
3. add it again

Answer (score 5):

As long as you are not modifying the hash code of the item you can update the item without removing it.
If your modifications change the hash code you will need to remove it and add again to keep the hash codes up to date.

Comment: Indeed; furthering this the solution would be to make the object mutable.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out

Answer (score 4):

The main purpose of Hashset is that: It holds a set of objects in a way that allows you to **easily** and **quickly** determine whether an object is **already in the set or not**.

To achieve that purpose it sacrificed some parts of the ability that allows you to manipulate its content.

You could consider using different type of collection or workaround this problem by using a Dictionary with keys and values of the same type.

Comment: The statement that it "sacrificed some parts to achieve its purpose" is misleading. I took the .net standard hashset and modified it to allow modification via a custom AddOrReplace() method. The code change was miniscule, and it had zero impact on the storage mechanisms or performance. The fact is that the .net built-in hashset is unnecessarily inflexible without reason.  Its poorly designed.